# Determining number of set bits in a char

Tags: c++, c

This program is supposed to determine how many units are stored in the value of the variable `c_val`, if each unit is stored as a set bit.
My question is: why did the author write `if (c % 2 == 1) count++;` then shift `c` to the right with this statement `c = c >> 1;`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    unsigned char c_val;
    printf("char value = ");
    scanf("%c", &c_val);
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char c = c_val;
    while(c){
        if (c % 2 == 1) count++;
        c = c >> 1;
    }
    printf("%d bits are set", count);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data size of type char is **always one byte** - no exceptions.  This code, however, calculates the [popcount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) - that is, the number of 1 bits - in `c_val`.

We can translate the relevant code from

```
while (c) {
    if (c % 2 == 1) count++;
    c = c >> 1;
}
```

to

```
while (c != 0) {
    if (c & 0x1 == 1) count++; /* if the rightmost bit of c is 1, then count++ */
    c = c / 2;
}
```

The last change I made works because right-shifting an unsigned integral data type (in this case, `unsigned char`) is equivalent to dividing by 2, with round-toward-zero semantics.

We can think of `c` as a conveyor belt of bits - zero bits come in from the left, and one bit falls off the right on each loop iteration.  If the rightmost bit is a 1, we increase the count by 1, and otherwise the count remains unchanged.  So, once `c` is filled with zero bits, we know that we have counted all the one bits, and exactly the one bits, so `count` contains the number of one bits in `c_val`.

Comment: A small readability improvement, IMO, would be `if(c & 0x1) count++`. I feel it makes it more clear that you're explicitly testing the bit.

Comment: Plus, it could be faster to boot. :-)

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Why not use >> instead of division by 2?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a function to determine the "size" of instances of the type `char` at all, but rather to determine the number of bits in a character that are set to 1.

The expression

```
c % 2 == 1
```

determines whether or not the least significant bit is a 1.

The shifting brings the second to last bit into the last position so it can be tested.

The condition `while (c)` means to keep counting 1s and shifting until the whole byte is all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just coding how many 1 bits in char c. "c % 2 === 1" checks if the last bit in "c" is 1. So we must use "c = c >> 1" to shift the other bits in "c" to the last position.

Answer (score 0):

> Other way to do the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

unsigned int f (unsigned int a , unsigned int b);

unsigned int f (unsigned int a , unsigned int b)
{
   return a ?   f ( (a&b) << 1, a ^b) : b;
}

int bitcount(int n) {
    int tot = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i<<1)
        if (n & i)
            ++tot;

    return tot;
}

int bitcount_sparse_ones(int n) {
    int tot = 0;

    while (n) {
        ++tot;
        n &= n - 1;
    }

    return tot;
}

int main()
{

int a = 12;
int b = 18;

int c = f(a,b);
printf("Sum = %d\n", c);

int  CountA = bitcount(a);
int  CountB = bitcount(b);

int CntA = bitcount_sparse_ones(a);
int CntB = bitcount_sparse_ones(b);

printf("CountA = %d and CountB = %d\n", CountA, CountB);
printf("CntA = %d and CntB = %d\n", CntA, CntB);
getch();

return 0;

}
```